# Comparing Long values using Collections.sort(object)

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I'm trying to sort a simple list of objects by a long - the below isn't working because one of the long strings is pushed to the top simply because it starts with a lower number. So I'm looking for a way to sort these by the actual long values directly

The current obj implementation looks something like the below. In the class I'm using this I call Collections.sort(trees);

```
public class Tree implements Comparable<Tree> {
    public String dist; //value is actually Long

    public int compareTo(Tree o) {
        return this.dist.compareTo(o.dist);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just compare the long-values of `dist` in your compareTo(Tree o) method?

Comment: Strings are compared alphabetically (not really but it's a good way to think of). Hence, 12 > 111. If you need to compare numbers use numbers, i.e. add one more field long. Or in the worst case compare the result of Long.parseLong(dist)

Comment: Turns out I was actually comparing a double the entire time - sorry guys (went with Double.compare as my actual solution) awarded what I felt was a great answer to the Long problem though - flag it for removal if nothing else

Comment: Use 'Long.compare(long x, long y)', see answer below

Answer (score 22, accepted):

why not actually store a long in there:

```
public class Tree implements Comparable<Tree> {
    public long dist; //value is actually Long

    public int compareTo(Tree o) {
        return this.dist < o.dist ? -1 :
            this.dist > o.dist ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

that or first compare the length of the strings and then compare them

```
public String dist; //value is actually Long

public int compareTo(Tree o) {
    if (this.dist.length() != o.dist.length())
      return this.dist.length() < o.dist.length() ? -1 : 1;//assume the shorter string is a smaller value
    else return this.dist.compareTo(o.dist);
}
```

Comment: Update: Since Java 7 you can do `Long.compare(x, y);` instead of writing such code yourself (not a revolution, but simpler).

Comment: In android, @ChristopheRoussy's solution works only for API 19 and above.

Comment: Update: You could even use `Comparator.comparingLong(x::y)`

Answer (score 52):

## `Long.compare( x , y )`

If you have an object that you want to sort on a `long` value, and it implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), in Java 7+ you can use [`Long.compare(long x, long y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,long)) (which returns an **`int`**)

E.g.

```
public class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject>
{
  public long id;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyObject obj) {
    return Long.compare(this.id, obj.id);
  }
}
```

Call `Collections.sort(my_objects)` where my_objects is something like

```
  List<MyObject> my_objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
  // + some code to populate your list
```

Comment: this is only available from API level 19

Comment: are there any ideas for pre KitKat?

Answer (score 13):

well if the dist variable is actually long then you might try using

```
public int compareTo(Tree o) {
    return Long.valueOf(this.dist).compareTo(Long.valueOf(o.dist));
}
```

Comment: will not compile (Long.parseLong return primitive long)

Answer (score 5):

Just an example I made for sorting Files by date using a Long comparator:

```
public File[] getAllFoldersByDescendingDate(File folder) {
    if (!folder.isDirectory()) {
        return null;
    }
    allFiles = folder.listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(allFiles, new Comparator<File>()
    {
        public int compare(final File o1, final File o2)
        {
            return Long.compare(o2.lastModified(), o1.lastModified());
        }
    });
    return allFiles;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you want to do things? Do you want to keep the current implementation of Comparable? If yes, use the sort method which takes a Comparator and implement a custom comparator which uses the actual "long" values of the string (`Long.parseLong(dist)`). If no, then just modify the current `compareTo` and use the Long values of the "dist".

BTW, I'd revisit the logic and ask myself why "dist" is of type String when it is actually a Long?

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
public class Tree implements Comparable<Tree> {
    public Long dist;

    public int compareTo(Tree o) {
        return this.dist.compareTo(o.dist);
    }
}
```

Comment: If performance can be an issue, it's better to use primitive. Otherwise, it seems that someone pointed out: "The emperor is naked!" :)