# How to sort arrayList<Object> by object attribute long in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, compare, long-integer

I have class (JavaBean if you want to call it like that)

```
class Tweet{

private millis; //number of millis since 1970
//other attributes and getters and setters, but i want to sort onlny by millis

public long getMillis() {
   return millis;
}

}
```

Comparator should be probably look simillar to this:

```
class TweetComparator implements Comparator {
     @Override
     public int  compare(Tweet t1, Tweet t2) {
     //something
     //this doesn't work
     //return t2.getMillis().compareTo(t1.getMillis());
     return ??;//what should be here?
     }

    }
```

This will be in program

```
List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
tweets.add(...); //just fill the list
//i need newest (with hightest millis value first) so I probably need to call reverse order
Collection.reverse(tweets)
Collection.sort(tweets, new TweetComparator());
```

I found some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176019/comparing-long-values-using-collections-sortobject)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894818/how-to-sort-arraylistlong-in-java-in-decreasing-order). But I don't know how to complete my code.

Comment: What happened when you tried your commented out code?

Comment: @RohitJain write error: cannot compareTo(long) on the primitive type long

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your comparator should look similar to this

```
class TweetComparator implements Comparator<Tweet> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Tweet t1, Tweet t2) {
        return Long.compare(t1.getMillis(), t2.getMillis()); 
    }
}
```

note that `static int Long.compare` is since Java 7

Comment: Collection.reverse(tweets) is unecessary

Comment: Are you sure? Even when I need it to print it then from newest to oldest (I mean from with hightest millis to lowest millis value)?

Comment: @user1097772.. Then move `t2.getMillis()` as first parameter in `compare`. And `t1.getMillis()` as second parameter. It will automatically sort in reverse.

Comment: Then you should sort, print (ascending), reverse, print (descending).

Comment: If you are here for android implementation then this is available from api 19 only.

Answer (score 4):

> Compare method Returns:
>    a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, >or greater than the second.

Logic -

```
if t1.millis > t2.millis 
   return -1;
else if t1.millis < t2.millis
   return +1;
```

Code -

```
class TweetComparator implements Comparator<Tweet> {
     @Override
     public int  compare(Tweet t1, Tweet t2) {
        if(s1.i>s2.i)
            return -1;
        else if(s1.i<s2.i)
            return +1;
        return 0;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
@Override
     public int  compare(Tweet t1, Tweet t2) {

     return t1.getMillis().compareTo(t2.getMillis());

     }
```

Change you mills varaible to Long if you want to use inbuilt compareTo method of Long class.
Otherwise inside compare method,compare your millis from t1 and t2 like below.

```
long t1Val = t1.getMillis();
long t2Val = t2.getMillis();
return (t1Val<t2Val? -1 : (t1Val ==t2Val? 0 : 1));
```

(Directly from original Long class)

Comment: this write error: cannot compareTo(long) on the primitive type long

Comment: @RohitJain I don't know how upvoted it, do you think the rest of my code is correctly used with Code used from Evgenyi Dorofeev?

Comment: @user1097772. Yeah everything seems to be fine. But why are you using `Collections.reverse`? You only want to sort the list right? And also remember to use generic version of `Comparator` as in the Evgenyi's answer.

Comment: @RohitJain Because the millis is time in millis from 1970 when was the post (Tweet) made, and I want get the newes first (so from highest to lovest valuest) this should make Collection.reverse or am I wrong?
Using generic version - I just can copy and paste the comparator from Evgenyi's it fits to the code or should be something different? 
I do this type of sorting first time so I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @user1097772.. Then you should first sort, and then reverse. Or, you can just sort in reverse order (No need to call `Collections.reverse()` in that case). You need to reverse the logic in Comparator.  Just put `t2.getMillis()` as first parameter in Evgenyi's code.

Comment: @RohitJain and how can I do it in Comparator? assume that I have 
class TweetComparator implements Comparator<Tweet> {
  public int compare(Tweet t1, Tweet t2) {
return Long.compare(t1.getMillis() ,t2.getMillis()); 
}
}

//ofcourse with Overide, but I can't put it in comment

Comment: @user1097772.. Change `return Long.compare(t1.getMillis() ,t2.getMillis());` to `return Long.compare(t2.getMillis() ,t1.getMillis());`