# Sort and merge two Arraylist of user defined type Library class

Tags: java, android, sorting, optimization, arraylist

**Aim :** I have to two sorted Arraylists of OSD Type(class part of an library inported). I need to merge them to create final sorted list(soerted by time in descending order) in the most optimized way.

> **Problem** : I can't modify the user defined OSD class as its part
>   of an  library and hence I cant edit and make it implements Comparable
>   class.    ***I have already created the function which performs the task,
>   but it I want to optimize the code and make it less expensive***.

I have come across many solutions that involve implementing Comparable,which I can't do.

Current working **code** that I want to optimize for better performance

```
private ArrayList<OSD> latestFistSortMergeOsds(
            ArrayList<OSD> awbThingTypeOSDs,
            ArrayList<OSD> LDDthingTypeOSDs) {
        ArrayList<OSD> sortedOsds = new ArrayList<OSD>();
        ArrayList<Long> timestampList = null;

        HashMap<Long, OSD> awbThingTypeOSDsHmap = null;
        if (awbThingTypeOSDs != null) {
            awbThingTypeOSDsHmap = new HashMap<Long, OSD>();
            for (OSD mOSD : awbThingTypeOSDs) {

                awbThingTypeOSDsHmap.put(mOSD.getUpdatedOn()
                        .getTime(), mOSD);
            }
            Log.i("sorted", "hmap" + awbThingTypeOSDsHmap);
        }
        HashMap<Long, OSD> LDDthingTypeOSDsHmap = null;
        if (LDDthingTypeOSDs != null) {
            LDDthingTypeOSDsHmap = new HashMap<Long,OSD>();
            for (OSD nOSD : LDDthingTypeOSDs) {

                LDDthingTypeOSDsHmap.put(nOSD.getUpdatedOn()
                        .getTime(), nOSD);
            }
        }
        // merge n sort timestamp
        if (awbThingTypeOSDsHmap != null) {
            timestampList = new ArrayList<Long>(awbThingTypeOSDsHmap.keySet());

            if (LDDthingTypeOSDsHmap != null) {
                ArrayList<Long> timestampListLDD = new ArrayList<Long>(
                        LDDthingTypeOSDsHmap.keySet());
                timestampList.addAll(timestampListLDD);
            }
            Collections.sort(timestampList, Collections.reverseOrder());// descending
            Log.i("sorted", "sorted keyList" + timestampList);
        }

        // merge sorted osds- latest first
        // timestamplist is sorted in desc order
        if (timestampList != null) {
            for (Long timestampKey : timestampList) {
                RareMediaCompanyOSD osd = null;

                osd = awbThingTypeOSDsHmap.get(timestampKey);
                if (osd == null) {
                    osd = LDDthingTypeOSDsHmap.get(timestampKey);
                }

                sortedOsds.add(osd);

            }
        }

        return sortedOsds;
    }
```

I have referred to the following links
[Comparing Long values using Collections.sort(object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176019/comparing-long-values-using-collections-sortobject)

[Comparing Long values using Collections.sort(object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176019/comparing-long-values-using-collections-sortobject)

[How to sort ArrayList<Long> in Java in decreasing order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894818/how-to-sort-arraylistlong-in-java-in-decreasing-order)

**Please suggest better usage of the Hashmaps or should I use some other DS instead of hashmap to optimize the code.**

P.S : its not a duplicate of these questions as I cannot edit the class and implement comparable,as its a part of library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a holder class, that holds an `OSD` object, which in turns implements `Comparable`

```
public class OSDHolder implements Comparable<OSDHolder> {

    private final OSD obj;

    public OSDHolder(OSD obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public long getTiming() {
        this.obj.getUpdatedOn().getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(OSDHolder o) {
        if (this.getTiming() > o.getTiming())
            return 1;
        else if (this.getTiming < o.getTiming())
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply add the contents of both lists to one list as `OSDHolder` type

```
ArrayList<OSDHolder> holders = new ArrayList<>();

for (OSD osd:awbThingTypeOSDs) {
    holders.add(new OSDHolder(osd));
}

for (OSD osd:LDDthingTypeOSDs) {
    holders.add(new OSDHolder(osd));
}
```

Then sort `holders` with either `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()`